# Why my created ZIP file doesn't work in a game?

Tags: java, windows, file, zip, corrupt

I've recently decided to write a launcher for my project. It simply downloads updated files from my server, unpacks them, merges some of the files (because their content varies on settings of the launcher) and packs them into one .zip file.

I'm sure the downloading and merging processes work perfectly, but the last one - zipping - doesn't.

Here's my code for zipping:

-- Here's where my not working code was. --

The .zip file is created correctly, but when I put it into the game dir, the game won't start (says it's corrupted). But if I open it with WinRar (yes, it opens without errors - the "Test" function shows no errors, too) and just add one, random file inside, the game STARTS!

Seems like WinRar re-creates the zip file in a correct way, but I can't make my launcher to do so.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

I've found another piece of code that is supposed to work:

```
      private static void zipDir(String zipFileName, String dir) throws Exception {
            File dirObj = new File(dir);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
            System.out.println("Creating : " + zipFileName);
            addDir(dirObj, out);
            out.close();
          }

          static void addDir(File dirObj, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
            File[] files = dirObj.listFiles();
            byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                addDir(files[i], out);
                continue;
              }
              String fap = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
              String rel_path = fap.substring(fap.indexOf("wypakowane") + 11).replace("\\", "/");
              FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fap);
              System.out.println(" Adding: " + rel_path);
              out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(rel_path));
              int len;
              while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
                out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
              }
              out.closeEntry();
              in.close();
            }
          }
```

I think it creates the directories inside the ZIP file. Unfortunately, the game still doesn't start...
("wypakowane" is the directory that contains all the files I want to put into ZIP file.)

**EDIT 2:**

I just compared both archives - the one created by my java app and the one created by WinRar by adding random file. They are identical, have the same CRCs, same attributes and unpack correctly. But the game crashes with the first one, and runs smoothly with the second one. I'm running out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: Ideas? Bundle winrar with your app, and have it add a junk file when you start your game? :-)

Comment: Is Java saving it in Zip64 format perhaps?

Comment: How can I check this? And what if it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be making entries for the directories themselves, only for the files. While the directory entries can be reconstructed from the file paths, if you don't put in the explicit entries a lot of software won't work correctly with the file.

A directory entry is just a regular entry where the path ends with "/".

Comment: I've modified my code (the second one). When I print out the contents of my zip, the structure is correct. What is the matter now?